# I have Ubuntu installed on an SSD. Will mounting my HDD to increase storage space reduce performance?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, dell, ssd

I'm new to Linux. Just bought a Dell Inspiron 5480 which has 125GB SSD and 1TB HD. Ubuntu came installed in the SSD. I need a computer with high performance, so it's good to use the SSD. However, I work with a large amount of data, so 125GB is not enough for me. The HD is available, but not mounted. If I mount it, would I lose performance on the SSD? What's the best way to mount it, considering I want a fast performance (SSD) and enough memory (HD)?

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: I use a similar sized SSD which is by far large enough to contain the OS and then a 500Go HDD which is mounted through fstab along with a 1TB NAS for additional storage and notice no drop in performance. Asking how to do that requires you amend your question or ask another.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if you mount >10TB disks, doesn't affect the speed but your laptop but will become very hot in summer and therefore a built-in fan often spins and it leads more battery consumption. And 2.5-inch HDD is slower than 3.5-inch HDD. I prefer some external HDDs when I work at home. If I can spend extra $200 for it, I might buy a 500+GB SSD and a 3-4TB network/usb HDD. No moving parts in the laptop is somewhat safe.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSDs are typically faster than HDDs at *reading* and *writing* information to the disk

Any data kept on your HDD will be subject to the limitations of the read/write speed of your HDD.

Your operating system and software need to access your disk frequently, so if you keep your OS and your software on the faster SSD, those tasks will benefit from the increased read and write speeds.

It is only when your computer needs to access files stored on your HDD that you will be subject to the slower read/write speeds of the HDD.

Comment: Thank you very much!!